# output '_coverage/_coverage_report.dat' was not created when using bazel coverage to generate lcov coverage file

Tags: go, bazel

I am using bazel to manage our golang project and I found an option online that I can generate coverage html file by generating a lcov coverage.dat file first and then use genhtml to generate the html.

However, I cannot get the first step successfully.

The command that I ran is

```
bazel coverage //common/model/foobar:go_default_test --test_output=all --combined_report=lcov --coverage_report_generator=@bazel_tools//tools/test/CoverageOutputGenerator/java/com/google/devtools/coverageoutputgenerator:Main --verbose_failures --cache_test_results=false
```

I also tried

```
bazel coverage //common/model/foobar:go_default_test --test_output=all --combined_report=lcov --coverage_report_generator=@bazel_tools//tools/test:coverage_report_generator --verbose_failures --cache_test_results=false
```

they all only generated the non lcov coverage.dat file and with an ERROR message

**output '_coverage/_coverage_report.dat' was not created**

**SEVERE: Parsing file bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/testlogs/common/model/foobar/go_default_test/coverage.dat
Mar 18, 2020 10:35:18 PM com.google.devtools.coverageoutputgenerator.Main getGcovInfoFiles
INFO: No gcov info file found.
Mar 18, 2020 10:35:18 PM com.google.devtools.coverageoutputgenerator.Main getProfdataFileOrNull
INFO: No .profdata file found.**

Details output below

Does any one know how to resolve this? I am using **bazel 2.2.0** and **go1.13.6 darwin/amd64**

```
(22:35:17) INFO: Current date is 2020-03-18
(22:35:17) DEBUG: Rule 'bazel_buildtools' indicated that a canonical reproducible form can be obtained by modifying arguments commit = "5bcc31df55ec1de770cb52887f2e989e7068301f", shallow_since = "1568030193 +0200" and dropping ["tag"]
(22:35:17) DEBUG: Call stack for the definition of repository 'bazel_buildtools' which is a git_repository (rule definition at /private/var/tmp/_bazel_peter/96e1142e20b2e61d4d24265e7f17358d/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git.bzl:195:18):
 - <builtin>
 - /Users/peter/Dev/myproject/WORKSPACE:72:1
(22:35:17) INFO: Using default value for --instrumentation_filter: "//common/model/foobar[/:]".
(22:35:17) INFO: Override the above default with --instrumentation_filter
(22:35:17) INFO: Build options --coverage_report_generator and --instrument_test_targets have changed, discarding analysis cache.
(22:35:17) INFO: Analyzed target //common/model/foobar:go_default_test (0 packages loaded, 7647 targets configured).
(22:35:17) INFO: Found 1 test target...
(22:35:18) INFO: From Testing //common/model/foobar:go_default_test:
==================== Test output for //common/model/foobar:go_default_test:
+ [[ -z bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/common/model/foobar/go_default_test.instrumented_files ]]
+ export ROOT=/private/var/tmp/_bazel_peter/96e1142e20b2e61d4d24265e7f17358d/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/197/execroot/myproject
+ ROOT=/private/var/tmp/_bazel_peter/96e1142e20b2e61d4d24265e7f17358d/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/197/execroot/myproject
+ [[ bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/common/model/foobar/go_default_test.instrumented_files != /* ]]
+ export COVERAGE_MANIFEST=/private/var/tmp/_bazel_peter/96e1142e20b2e61d4d24265e7f17358d/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/197/execroot/myproject/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/common/model/foobar/go_default_test.instrumented_files
+ COVERAGE_MANIFEST=/private/var/tmp/_bazel_peter/96e1142e20b2e61d4d24265e7f17358d/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/197/execroot/myproject/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/common/model/foobar/go_default_test.instrumented_files
+ export COVERAGE_DIR=_coverage/common/model/foobar/go_default_test/test
+ COVERAGE_DIR=_coverage/common/model/foobar/go_default_test/test
+ [[ _coverage/common/model/foobar/go_default_test/test == /private/var/tmp/_bazel_peter/96e1142e20b2e61d4d24265e7f17358d/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/197/execroot/myproject* ]]
+ COVERAGE_DIR=/private/var/tmp/_bazel_peter/96e1142e20b2e61d4d24265e7f17358d/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/197/execroot/myproject/_coverage/common/model/foobar/go_default_test/test
+ mkdir -p /private/var/tmp/_bazel_peter/96e1142e20b2e61d4d24265e7f17358d/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/197/execroot/myproject/_coverage/common/model/foobar/go_default_test/test
+ COVERAGE_OUTPUT_FILE=bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/testlogs/common/model/foobar/go_default_test/coverage.dat
+ [[ bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/testlogs/common/model/foobar/go_default_test/coverage.dat == /private/var/tmp/_bazel_peter/96e1142e20b2e61d4d24265e7f17358d/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/197/execroot/myproject* ]]
+ COVERAGE_OUTPUT_FILE=/private/var/tmp/_bazel_peter/96e1142e20b2e61d4d24265e7f17358d/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/197/execroot/myproject/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/testlogs/common/model/foobar/go_default_test/coverage.dat
+ export JAVA_COVERAGE_FILE=/private/var/tmp/_bazel_peter/96e1142e20b2e61d4d24265e7f17358d/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/197/execroot/myproject/_coverage/common/model/foobar/go_default_test/test/jvcov.dat
+ JAVA_COVERAGE_FILE=/private/var/tmp/_bazel_peter/96e1142e20b2e61d4d24265e7f17358d/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/197/execroot/myproject/_coverage/common/model/foobar/go_default_test/test/jvcov.dat
+ export COVERAGE=1
+ COVERAGE=1
+ export BULK_COVERAGE_RUN=1
+ BULK_COVERAGE_RUN=1
+ for name in '"$LCOV_MERGER"'
+ [[ ! -e bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/external/io_bazel_rules_go/go/tools/builders/lcov_merger ]]
+ [[ -z '' ]]
+ export GCOV_PREFIX_STRIP=3
+ GCOV_PREFIX_STRIP=3
+ export GCOV_PREFIX=/private/var/tmp/_bazel_peter/96e1142e20b2e61d4d24265e7f17358d/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/197/execroot/myproject/_coverage/common/model/foobar/go_default_test/test
+ GCOV_PREFIX=/private/var/tmp/_bazel_peter/96e1142e20b2e61d4d24265e7f17358d/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/197/execroot/myproject/_coverage/common/model/foobar/go_default_test/test
+ export LLVM_PROFILE_FILE=/private/var/tmp/_bazel_peter/96e1142e20b2e61d4d24265e7f17358d/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/197/execroot/myproject/_coverage/common/model/foobar/go_default_test/test/%h-%p-%m.profraw
+ LLVM_PROFILE_FILE=/private/var/tmp/_bazel_peter/96e1142e20b2e61d4d24265e7f17358d/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/197/execroot/myproject/_coverage/common/model/foobar/go_default_test/test/%h-%p-%m.profraw
+ [[ ! -z '' ]]
+ cd /private/var/tmp/_bazel_peter/96e1142e20b2e61d4d24265e7f17358d/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/197/execroot/myproject/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/common/model/foobar/darwin_amd64_stripped/go_default_test.runfiles/myproject
+ /private/var/tmp/_bazel_peter/96e1142e20b2e61d4d24265e7f17358d/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/197/execroot/myproject/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/common/model/foobar/darwin_amd64_stripped/go_default_test.runfiles/myproject/common/model/foobar/darwin_amd64_stripped/go_default_test
PASS
coverage: 48.1% of statements
+ TEST_STATUS=0
+ touch /private/var/tmp/_bazel_peter/96e1142e20b2e61d4d24265e7f17358d/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/197/execroot/myproject/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/testlogs/common/model/foobar/go_default_test/coverage.dat
+ [[ 0 -ne 0 ]]
+ cd /private/var/tmp/_bazel_peter/96e1142e20b2e61d4d24265e7f17358d/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/197/execroot/myproject
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ LCOV_MERGER_CMD='bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/external/io_bazel_rules_go/go/tools/builders/lcov_merger --coverage_dir=/private/var/tmp/_bazel_peter/96e1142e20b2e61d4d24265e7f17358d/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/197/execroot/myproject/_coverage/common/model/foobar/go_default_test/test   --output_file=/private/var/tmp/_bazel_peter/96e1142e20b2e61d4d24265e7f17358d/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/197/execroot/myproject/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/testlogs/common/model/foobar/go_default_test/coverage.dat   --filter_sources=/usr/bin/.+   --filter_sources=/usr/lib/.+   --filter_sources=/usr/include.+   --filter_sources=.*external/.+   --source_file_manifest=/private/var/tmp/_bazel_peter/96e1142e20b2e61d4d24265e7f17358d/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/197/execroot/myproject/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/common/model/foobar/go_default_test.instrumented_files'
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ JAVA_RUNFILES=
+ exec bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/external/io_bazel_rules_go/go/tools/builders/lcov_merger --coverage_dir=/private/var/tmp/_bazel_peter/96e1142e20b2e61d4d24265e7f17358d/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/197/execroot/myproject/_coverage/common/model/foobar/go_default_test/test --output_file=/private/var/tmp/_bazel_peter/96e1142e20b2e61d4d24265e7f17358d/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/197/execroot/myproject/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/testlogs/common/model/foobar/go_default_test/coverage.dat --filter_sources=/usr/bin/.+ --filter_sources=/usr/lib/.+ --filter_sources=/usr/include.+ '--filter_sources=.*external/.+' --source_file_manifest=/private/var/tmp/_bazel_peter/96e1142e20b2e61d4d24265e7f17358d/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/197/execroot/myproject/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/common/model/foobar/go_default_test.instrumented_files
================================================================================
(22:35:18) INFO: LCOV coverage report is located at /private/var/tmp/_bazel_peter/96e1142e20b2e61d4d24265e7f17358d/execroot/myproject/bazel-out/_coverage/_coverage_report.dat
 and execpath is bazel-out/_coverage/_coverage_report.dat
(22:35:18) INFO: From CoverageReport _coverage/_coverage_report.dat:
Mar 18, 2020 10:35:18 PM com.google.devtools.coverageoutputgenerator.Main getTracefiles
INFO: Found 1 tracefiles.
Mar 18, 2020 10:35:18 PM com.google.devtools.coverageoutputgenerator.Main parseFiles
SEVERE: Parsing file bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/testlogs/common/model/foobar/go_default_test/coverage.dat
Mar 18, 2020 10:35:18 PM com.google.devtools.coverageoutputgenerator.Main getGcovInfoFiles
INFO: No gcov info file found.
Mar 18, 2020 10:35:18 PM com.google.devtools.coverageoutputgenerator.Main getProfdataFileOrNull
INFO: No .profdata file found.
Mar 18, 2020 10:35:18 PM com.google.devtools.coverageoutputgenerator.Main main
WARNING: There was no coverage found.
(22:35:18) ERROR: output '_coverage/_coverage_report.dat' was not created
(22:35:18) ERROR: not all outputs were created or valid
Target //common/model/foobar:go_default_test up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/common/model/foobar/darwin_amd64_stripped/go_default_test
(22:35:18) INFO: Elapsed time: 1.124s, Critical Path: 0.51s
(22:35:18) INFO: 4 processes: 4 darwin-sandbox.
(22:35:18) FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
//common/model/foobar:go_default_test                  PASSED in 0.1s
  /private/var/tmp/_bazel_peter/96e1142e20b2e61d4d24265e7f17358d/execroot/myproject/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/testlogs/common/model/foobar/go_default_test/coverage.dat

Executed 1 out of 1 test: 1 test passes.
```

Comment: are u able to solve this issue?

Comment: @rishi007bansod nope

Comment: I'm running into this too and I suspect bazel is using an old version of the CoverageOutputGenerator. https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/commit/21f633ca58d45b4d270668ddb147f680931efef3#diff-d5abc188e36d1d3e9fb3ed6b915cb385 modifies the generator to print Info messages instead of severe and even when I update to bazel 3.1 I get Severe messages.

Comment: Any updates on this? I think we're able to repro this on Bazel 4.0?